# How to identify the presence of # in a string using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have file some where in the file I have lines starting with `#define`. 
I want to replace the whole line which is starting with #define with some other string, but my code is not recognizing the string. How can I do it?

The file has data like

```
   extern const  Bit_Fld Alert;
   extern const  Bit_Fld selected;
   #define Gettest1_TX_DEV_MODE_CH0()      Read_byte_bit_Fld(&test1_DEV_MODE_CH0)
   #define Gettest2_TX_DEBUG_MODE_CH0()    Read_byte_bit_Fld(&test2_DEBUG_MODE_CH0)
   #define Gettest3_TX_FUNN_STAT_CH0()     Read_byte_bit_Fld(&test3_FUNN_STAT_CH0)
```

I want to change that data which starts with `#define` as below

```
   int Gettest1_DEV_MODE_CH0(void)        { return (Byte_bit_Fld(&test1_DEV_MODE_CH0));}
```

Similarly remaining lines with `#define` as above with out changing any other data except for the lines with `#define`. How can it be done?

how to edit that particular string and replace it in that same file?

n how to delete that 2nd string replace it like

```
   int Gettest1_DEV_MODE_CH0(void)
```

Comment: In a regex, `#` has no special significance.  Use `/^#define/`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will work as you intended if you use the binding operator `=~` and not the assignment operator `=`

```
 if($line =~ /^\#define/)
```

Also, `#` is not a special character in regular expressions, so escaping it is optional.

```
 if($line =~ /^#define/)
```

Comment: thank you @mob i need to replace that whole line in a file with withe other data as i mentioned in the question in the same file is it possible to replace that string and print some other string in the same file with out any data in that getting affected?

Comment: @Naidu - what do you think of M42's solution?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/^#define\s+(\w+)\(\)\s+Read_(\w*Fld.+)/int $1(void) { return ($2);}/;
    say $_;
}
__DATA__
extern const  Bit_Fld Alert;
extern const  Bit_Fld selected;
#define Get_DEV_MODE()      Read_Fld(&DEV_MODE)
#define Get_DEBUG_MODE()    Read_Fld(&DEBUG_MODE)
#define Get_FUNN_STAT()     Read__Fld(&FUNN_STAT)
#define Gettest1_TX_DEV_MODE_CH0()      Read_byte_bit_Fld(&test1_DEV_MODE_CH0)
#define Gettest2_TX_DEBUG_MODE_CH0()    Read_byte_bit_Fld(&test2_DEBUG_MODE_CH0)
#define Gettest3_TX_FUNN_STAT_CH0()     Read_byte_bit_Fld(&test3_FUNN_STAT_CH0)
```

**output:**

```
extern const  Bit_Fld Alert;
extern const  Bit_Fld selected;
int Get_DEV_MODE(void) { return (Fld(&DEV_MODE));}
int Get_DEBUG_MODE(void) { return (Fld(&DEBUG_MODE));}
int Get_FUNN_STAT(void) { return (Fld(&FUNN_STAT));}
int Gettest1_TX_DEV_MODE_CH0(void) { return (byte_bit_Fld(&test1_DEV_MODE_CH0));}
int Gettest2_TX_DEBUG_MODE_CH0(void) { return (byte_bit_Fld(&test2_DEBUG_MODE_CH0));}
int Gettest3_TX_FUNN_STAT_CH0(void) { return (byte_bit_Fld(&test3_FUNN_STAT_CH0));}
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
    ^           : start of string
    #define     : literally #define
    \s+         : one or more spaces
    (\w+)       : group 1, one or more word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    \(\)        : a pair of parenthesis
    \s+         : one or more spaces
    Read_       : literally Read_
    (           : start of group 2
        \w*     : 0 or more wword character
        Fld     : literally Fld
        .+      : One or more characterter
    )           : end group 
/               : regex delimiter
```

for example the input line:

```
#define Gettest1_TX_DEV_MODE_CH0()  Read_byte_bit_Fld(&test1_DEV_MODE_CH0)
        ^________  $1  ________^         ^__________    $2   ____________^
```

will give (with the replacement part: `int $1(void) { return ($2);}`):

```
int Gettest1_TX_DEV_MODE_CH0(void) { return (byte_bit_Fld(&test1_DEV_MODE_CH0));}
```

Comment: hi i have made some changes to my string for that changes i tried to edit the code you have given but am unable to get the result n the command prompt is hanginging when ever am trying to run that script 
#define Gettest_TX_DEV_MODE_Ch0()      Read_Byte_Bit_Fld(&test_TX_DEV_MODE_Ch0)

Comment: @Naidu: I've edited my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: sorry M42 i dont know what the issue is but there is no effect in my file with the code you have given

Comment: @Naidu: What do you mean by `no effects`? Isn't the output what you want? How do you use the code I've given? You may edit your question and say what you want foreach input line.

Comment: i have a doubt as per your code it must make changes in the same file from where the data is being taken right ? if that is the case its not working for me but i dont understant what is the problem ,, do you mind to explain this statement s/^#define\s+(\w+)()\s+Read_(\w*Fld.+)/int $1(void) { return ($2);}/; i mean what does that statement do exactly n where are you printing that ?

Comment: @Naidu: See my edit. The modified line is printed on standard output.

Comment: Thanks a lot mr M42 for your effort

Answer (score 1):

```
chomp $line;
if($line =~ m/^#define/)
{
    print OUTPUTFILE $whatever, "\n";
}
else
{
    print OUTPUTFILE $line, "\n";
}
```

This will find all lines that start with the exact term `#define`.

Easiest way to go when you want to replace some but not all lines is to have a second file open where you print to as `OUTPUTFILE`. You just iterate all your lines and if you encounter something you need replaced, you just print to the output whatever you want to replace it with and simply print the other lines as they are.